# Solve the equation $\sqrt{3x^2-7x-30}-\sqrt{2x^2-7x-5}=x-5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> **Problem Statement:-**
>
> Solve the equation $\sqrt{3x^2-7x-30}-\sqrt{2x^2-7x-5}=x-5$

---

**Attempt at solution:-**

Let $\alpha=\sqrt{3x^2-7x-30}\;\;\; \text{&} \;\;\;\beta=\sqrt{2x^2-7x-5}$.

Then, we have $$\alpha-\beta=x-5\tag{1}$$

And, we have $$\alpha^2-\beta^2=x^2-25\tag{2}$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have 
$$\alpha+\beta=\dfrac{(x-5)(x+5)}{x-5}=x+5\qquad(\therefore x\neq5)\tag{3}$$

From $(1)$ and $(3)$, we get
$$\alpha=\sqrt{3x^2-7x-30}=x\qquad\qquad\beta=\sqrt{2x^2-7x-5}=5$$

On solving any one of $\alpha=x$ or $\beta=5$, we get $x=6,-\dfrac{5}{2}$.

On putting $x=-\dfrac{5}{2}$, $\alpha=x$ is not satisfied. Hence, $x=6$ is the only solution.

But as in $(3)$, we have ruled out $x=5$, as a solution then we can't put $x=5$ in the original equation. But, if we do put $x=5$ in the original equation we see that it is indeed satisfied. So, I tried a solution which also gives $x=5$ as a solution. So I picked the last solution from the $(2)$ without cancelling $(x-5)$.

$$(x-5)(\alpha+\beta)=x^2-25\implies (x-5)(\alpha+\beta-(x+5))=0$$.

Now, I am pretty much stuck here.

**Edit-1:-** I just saw now and feel pretty stupid about it.

If we proceed from the last step i.e. $(x-5)(\alpha+\beta-(x+5))=0$, we get 
$$(x-5)(\alpha+\beta-(x+5))=0\implies (x-5)=0\;\;\;\text{ or }\;\;\;\alpha+\beta=x+5$$

So we have the following equations to be solved:-

$$\alpha-\beta=x-5\\
\alpha+\beta=x+5\\
x-5=0$$

Which results in $x=5,6$.

> Now, since I have put so much effort in posting this question, I might as well ask for better solutions if you can come up with one. And, please don't post a solution which includes a lot of squaring to result into a quartic equation.

Comment: $2-1=6-5$, but $2^2-1^2\ne6^2-5^2$

Comment: @SimpleArt-Try squaring and subtracting $\beta$ from $\alpha$, you will surely know how did I get $\alpha^2-\beta^2=x^-25$

Comment: Your logic for $x\ne5$ is wrong.  You must check the **original** equation for which $x$ values are allowed.

Comment: Oh, well, that's quite a nice thing.

Comment: Your solution is correct (almost). There is no reason to discard x=-5/2. It *is* a solution. Also I am not sure I follow your rationale in the edit. You point out correctly that you should check for x=5 (because your your method was excluding it). Once you find it satisfies the equation, you just stop there declaring it as another solution.

Comment: @Thanassis-I did provide the reason for excluding $x=\dfrac{-5}{2}$ as a solution because it did not satisfy $\alpha=x$

Comment: $x=-5/2$ is not a solution since it does not satisfy the given equation.

Comment: @mathlove-oh no you are right, I used $x=-\dfrac{5}{2}$ to solve the LHS and $x=\dfrac{5}{2}$ to solve the RHS. I think my brain fluids are leaking. Gonna delete the second edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rewriting as $$\sqrt{3x^2-7x-30}=x-5+\sqrt{2x^2-7x-5}$$
after squaring we get
$$3x^2-7x-30-(x-5)^2-2x^2+7x+5=2(x-5)\sqrt{2x^2-7x-5}$$
simplifying 
$$10x-50=2(x-5)\sqrt{2x^2-7x-5}$$
$$5x-25=(x-5)\sqrt{2x^2-7x-5}$$
squaring again
$$- \left( 2\,x+5 \right)  \left( x-6 \right)  \left( x-5 \right) ^{2}=0$$
from here you will get the possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

As $(\sqrt{x^2-7x-30})^2-(\sqrt{2x^2-7x-5})^2=(x+5)(x-5),$

$$\sqrt{3x^2-7x-30}-\sqrt{2x^2-7x-5}=x-5$$

$$\implies \sqrt{3x^2-7x-30}+\sqrt{2x^2-7x-5}=x+5$$

Adding we get $$x=\sqrt{3x^2-7x-30}\  \ \ \ (1)$$

Squaring $(1)$ we get  $$0=2x^2-7x-30=(2x+5)(x-6)$$

Now for real $x,x=\sqrt{3x^2-7x-30}\ge0$

Answer (score 0):

Your $(2)$ is incorrect.  Instead, we should square both sides of $(1)$ to get

$$(\alpha-\beta)^2=(x-5)^2$$

$$\alpha^2-2\alpha\beta+\beta^2=(x-5)^2$$

$$2\alpha\beta=(x-5)^2-\alpha^2-\beta^2$$

Square both sides again

$$4\alpha^2\beta^2=\left[(x-5)^2-\alpha^2-\beta^2\right]^2$$

Now all radicals are removed and you should get something like two quartic polynomials.  Using the rational roots theorem, we get

[$$x=5,6\tag{Click here}$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x-5%3Dsqrt(3x%5E2-7x-30)-sqrt(2x%5E2-7x-5))

And keeping in mind that we must have

$$3x^2-7x-30>0,\ 2x^2-7x-5>0$$

These are the only solutions.

Comment: I tell you, these edits make me feel slightly agitated.  XD

Comment: +1 for the use of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ --- it is what "algebra" is for. "Now all radicals are removed and you should get something like two quartic polynomials." Good hint.